# Find the dimension of $\ker f $ and a base of $\ker f$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $f:\mathbb{K}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{K}^4$ a linear map and $a$ an scalar such that:

$\text{(i)} f(1,0,0,0)=(1,0,2,2), f(0,1,0,0)=(a,3,-1,1)$

(ii) the $ \ker f$ contains the subspace $x=y=z$

(iii) exists a vector (no null) of $\mathbb{K}^4$ that transforms through $f$ in its triple

**Find the dimension of  $ \ker f $ and a  base.**

---

I know the  vectors $(1,0,2,2)$ and $(a,3,-1,1) $ are independents then $\dim\text{(im}(f))\ge 2 $

but now I don't how to continue . Can you help me?

Comment: You mean $\dim \ker (f) \le 2$ ?

Comment: You know more: $\dim\ker f \color{red}=2$.

Comment: can you explain the statement "that transforms through f in its triple"

Comment: $f(v)=3v$ and since $v\neq 0$ then $3$ is an eigenvalue and $v$ an eigenvector.

Comment: (iii) imposes that $a=1$

Comment: @stity sorry I mean $\dim\text{(im}(f)\geq 2$

Comment: @David So by the rank-nullity theorem, $\dim \ker f \le 4 - 2 = 2$, right?

Comment: @AlexVong Yes! and then a base is {(1,1,1,0),(0,0,0,1)} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $ker f$  contains the subspace $x=y=z$ and hence contain the vector $(1,1,1,0)$.

Comment: and the vector $(0,0,0,1)$